# Copy a Tag to the Branch in SVN

Tags: svn, tags, branch

I committed to a Tag rather than the working Branch copy.  Is there a way to copy my Tag over to the Branch so I can commit it to the SVN and make it the de facto copy and stop committing updates to the Tag?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Tags and branches are exactly the same thing in SVN. A tag is just conventionally in tags, and is supposed to be read-only, whereas a branch is conventionally in branches and is read-write.

```
svn copy http://your.server.com/repo/tags/yourtag http://your.server.com/repo/branches/yournewbranch
```

If the branch already exists, then just merge the commits you did to the tag to the working copy (pointing to the branch):

```
svn merge http://your.server.com/repo/tags/yourtag@150 \
          http://your.server.com/repo/tags/yourtag@212 \
          my-working-copy-pointing-to-the-branch
```

All this is well explained in the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  Merge will not work as someone else already updated the branch with changes I don't need.  Merging maintains those changes and then adds mine so I end up with a mix of the two.  Revert for some reason is not working on the main Branch, thus the reason I am looking to completely override the Branch with my Tag.  An ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Select **needed** revision (before unwanted commit) in branchURL. After merging (in  WC) commit it as new additinal brach (for safety)

Comment: @javaMe: Then delete the branch and recreate it using the first command I gave you. But reverting to a previous revision should work. Read the SVN book: it's full of useful information.